# How to create and store JSON objects in vb.net executable?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I'm having trouble finding a way to convert a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` into a JSON Object String in a vb.net console application.

When it was in ASP I used the JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize() method to serialize the dictionary, but now I'm in vb.net console and have no access to the System.Web classes

It has to be done in an executable that can be run automatically (from a windows scheduled task), once every day, to store data in text files (later we'll move to a seperate, temp database), so that there is less load on the database.

Previously this was done in asmx scripts, but that worked only in testing, it would be impractical for it to be run from a web browser by a person everyday, because it leaves room for human error. 
We've tried to open the pages in IExplorer from batch scripts, but the browser gives security errors regarding the page's security certificate, and that needs human interaction, this needs to be automated ASAP.

I wouldn't mind if one of you had your own function that converted at least an array into a JSON object String, so I can store it

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: `I'm in vb.net console and have no access to the System.Web`, You can still use it by addding a *reference* to System.Web (or System.Web.Extensions).

Comment: @I4V so do I Import it? because I get an error when Importing; System.Web.Script does not exist, and I need the JavaScriptSerializer class from System.Web.Script.Serialization

Comment: @pythonian29033 `References/Add reference`

Comment: you'll have to explain a little more, sorry, I'm not a .NET developer

Comment: Found it! -> Project > Add Reference

Comment: @I4V make your comment an answer so I can accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When it was in ASP I used the JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize() method to serialize the dictionary, but now I'm in vb.net console and have no access to the System.Web classes

Even in Console applications you can use your *JavaScriptSerializer*. Just add reference to *System.Web.Extensions*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to serialize vb arrays to JSON. Don't think that there is a lib that can serialize Dictionary.

By the way, I'm calling aspx pages with the following .vbs script and it's working fine without any security issues:

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

o.open "GET", "http://myserver/myjob.aspx", False
o.setRequestHeader "timeout", "1800000"
o.send

WScript.Quit(0)
```

and a batch:

```
wscript c:\myscript.vbs
```

Comment: isn't this vbScript?
The issue is that the company's server is providing its own security certificate, so the browser gives an error, this answer does not relate to my problem

Comment: The first sentence is the answer to your question (before you edit it). And the second is how I open webpages in a vbscript. Haven't tested it with ssl but might work as well.

Comment: I used a batch script in cmd to open the url in the browser already. . .I'm not sure you understood what the problem with that was, but I solved it with someone else's answer, thanks anyways